# SQL Server : error on insert into TempTable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created a `@TempTable` with a additional column for identity.

Here is the query:

```
declare @TempTable table
                   (
                       [EmpEnrollNumber] [nvarchar](MAX), 
                       [Date] [datetime],
                       rowuniq int identity(1,1)
                   );

SET IDENTITY_INSERT @TempTable ON;

INSERT INTO @TempTable 
    SELECT * 
    FROM [Tempdata]

SET IDENTITY_INSERT @TempTable OFF;
```

I get these errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near '@TempTable'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near '@TempTable'.

How to turn identity insert on for `@TempTable`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45627512/sql-temptable-identity-column-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to alter a **table variable**. However, you can declare a temp table and do this task. Check the below code.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPTABLE([EMPENROLLNUMBER] [NVARCHAR](MAX), [DATE] [DATETIME],ROWUNIQ INT IDENTITY(1,1));

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #TEMPTABLE ON;
INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE SELECT * FROM [TEMPDATA]
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #TEMPTABLE OFF;
```

**Note:** When IDENTITY_INSERT in ON, your insert query should be like this.

```
INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE([EMPENROLLNUMBER], [DATE], ROWUNIQ) VALUES(2, '2017-08-11', 4)
```

When it's OFF, you can insert like this.

```
INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE VALUES(3, '2017-08-11')
```

Hope it is much clear now.

Comment: You need to mention the column list in Insert when you are setting Identity_insert ON

Comment: @Pரதீப் It gives me error :- Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: In the `select` i have not included the Indentity Column.

Comment: @Pரதீப்: Yes, I have added it to the answer now. Thanks

Comment: I got new errors now :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45627512/sql-temptable-identity-column-not-working

Comment: @Anup - you are clearly confused by what `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` actually does. I suggest you take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql

Answer (score 3):

You cannot alter a `table variable` in Sql Server. So it is not possible to `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON/OFF` on a table variable

Try using `#temp table` instead of table variable.

Here is the relevant connect item : 
[SET IDENTITY INSERT on table variables](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/757012/set-identity-insert-on-table-variables)

**Note :** You need to mention the column list in `Insert` when you are setting `Identity_insert ON`