# SQL - Temptable Identity Column not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a `#TempTable`. And reason for creating it is that in the Main table i don't have the Unique column so I am copying data from the `Main` table into `#TempTable` with a extra column with Identity.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPTABLE
(
     rowuniq INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
     [CARDNO] [CHAR](10), 
     [OFFICEPUNCH] [DATETIME]
);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #TEMPTABLE ON;

INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE(rowuniq, CARDNO,OFFICEPUNCH) 
    SELECT CARDNO, OFFICEPUNCH 
    FROM [Tempdata]

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #TEMPTABLE OFF;
```

Error:

> The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

Comment: Where is the value for `rowuniq` column ? In `select` list first column should have value for `rowuniq` column

Comment: @Pரதீப் Will it not auto generate. It is not in the Main table so i have created TempTable. If it was there in Main table then i won't have created TempTable.

Comment: You do not need `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` to generate IDs in temp table. You only need to use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` when you want to copy values from `SELECT`. Please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql to see how it works.

Comment: @Alex Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined **three** columns in the `INSERT INTO` statement - but the `SELECT` only provides **two**.

Change your code to so you're *not* inserting values into your `IDENTITY` column:

```
-- NOT NEEDED! SET IDENTITY_INSERT #TEMPTABLE ON;

INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE(CARDNO, OFFICEPUNCH) 
    SELECT CARDNO, OFFICEPUNCH 
    FROM [Tempdata]

-- NOT NEEDED! SET IDENTITY_INSERT #TEMPTABLE OFF;
```

Comment: Thanks. People here are targeting this question, so i will delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign the value for an Identity Column.

You can try the following

#### Solution #1:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPTABLE
(
     rowuniq INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
     [CARDNO] [CHAR](10), 
     [OFFICEPUNCH] [DATETIME]
);

INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE(rowuniq, CARDNO,OFFICEPUNCH) 
    SELECT NULL, CARDNO, OFFICEPUNCH 
    FROM [Tempdata] ORDER BY rowuniq
```

#### Solution #2:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPTABLE
(
     rowuniq INT NOT NULL, 
     [CARDNO] [CHAR](10), 
     [OFFICEPUNCH] [DATETIME]
);

INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE(rowuniq, CARDNO,OFFICEPUNCH) 
    SELECT rowuniq, CARDNO, OFFICEPUNCH 
    FROM [Tempdata] ORDER BY rowuniq
```